# What system (Windows Web based / Form based / or anyother ) is used to run RFID card management system?

Tags: system, rfid

I need suggestion about making Card Membership management system using RFID . My question is , Which system would be more stable and easy to maintain for it ?

Is php/html web based system with mysql would be stable in windows PC ?
How about .net based system with MSSQL as database  ?
What UI system is used in Bank ATM machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Our University is using .net with MSSQL. 
In online mode it stuck. We have 12 client devices and every request to remote server cost you 20 sec.
As a solution every client is stand alone and collecting data. Then we push the data over night to the server. If you have only few clients I would try MySQL with immediately request.